# Format vsto listobject before linked to datatable

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a vsto application that populates an Excel sheet.

First I populate the datatable. The next function is to create a vsto listobject:

```
// Populate the sheet
XlsInterop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (XlsInterop.Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
extendedWorksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(worksheet);
XlsInterop.Excel.Range cell = extendedWorksheet.Range["A1"];


excelItemsList = extendedWorksheet.Controls.AddListObject(cell, sheetName);
excelItemsList.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = true;
excelItemsList.DataSource = dt;
excelItemsList.ListColumns[5].Range.NumberFormat = "@";
```

Now the problem is that in column "5" I have values like 005, 004. In Excel, the values display as 5 and 4. How can I make sure that the values in Excel show the same values as in my database?

If I change my code like:

```
excelItemsList.SetDataBinding(dt);
excelItemsList.ListColumns[5].Range.NumberFormat = "@";
excelItemsList.SetDataBinding(dt);
```

It is doing what I want, but I don't think that this is the way to go.

Comment: Are you still having an issue with the format?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many leading zeros you need, you can then format the column with that.

```
.NumberFormat = "000";
```

The column would then still be evaluated as a number.